# How to compile dynamic library with static files (.a) for a JNI application on linux?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I'm using **Ubuntu 14.04**

I'm new in JNI so I'm not familiar in JNI and also English. I'm using **Ubuntu 14.04**

What I did

Java

```
class Hello {
        public native void sayHello();

        static { System.loadLibrary("myapp"); }

        public static void main(String[] args){
                new Hello().sayHello();
        }
}
```

compile java code and make header file command

```
javac Hello.java

javah Hello
```

C code

```
#include "myapp.h"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloJNI_sayHello (JNIEnv *env, jobject job ){
    printf("Saying hello\n");
}
```

compile c code command (And I have 5 static compiled library like *.a).

```
gcc -shared -fPIC -o libmyapp.so -I"path/to/include/jni" -I"path/to/include/myapp" path/to/lib/libmyapp1.a path/to/lib/libmyapp2.a path/to/lib/libmyapp3.a path/to/lib/libmyapp4.a path/to/lib/libmyapp5.a -lm -lpthread -lc -lz Hello.c
```

that generates the file `libmyapp.so`

After compilation, I check the function naming with nm:

```
$ nm libmyapp.so | grep say 
00000000000031a0 T _Java_Hello_sayHello
```

I got error when I try to run it with `java -Djava.library.path=src/ Hello` I have this error:

```
java: symbol lookup error: /path/to/myapplication.so : undefined symbol: myfunc_init
```

So in my mind, obviously, there is something wrong with during compilation of c shared library.

Why do I get a symbol lookup error every time I want to call myfunc_init, what is the reason? Please provide the solution and correct way to compile shared library. And It is possible to load static library below Java 7.If it is not possible how can I build a dynamic library from a static one.

I hope you will be able to provide the information.

Comment: I which library is `myfunc_init`? Did you check if it is also in the .so you're building (use `nm` as with `sayHello`)?

Comment: No `myfunc_init` function is in a static library ("myapp1.a")

Comment: If it's not in any of your libraries that might be the reason it can't be found. Find out where it is and link that library too.

Comment: yeah.! OK will try.